# With CLion, how do I set an environment variable for the cmake build?

Tags: environment-variables, clion

I'm new to CLion; and have imported a `CMakeLists.txt` project. To properly configure, I need to set a certain environment variable.

Now, I know I can do this by setting that variable before invoking CLion; but assuming that I haven't, or that I want to change things at runtime - can I do so? If I can, then how? I still don't know my way around the IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [FAQ](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2014/09/clion-answers-frequently-asked-questions/)

> **Q: How to pass environment variables and parameters to CMake in CLion?**
>
> A: The best way is to use Preferences/Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | CMake dialog.

So: *File* > *Settings* > *Build, Execution, Deployment* > *CMake*

There's *Environment* field in the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. Start a build, or other get the CMake console pane on your Window
2. To the pane's left, there should be two columns of icons.
3. Choose the gear-wheel icon
4. Choose CMake Settings
5. Now you get a dialog where you can set either environment variables or CMake command-line parameters (which could involve definition, e.g. `-DCMAKE_BUILD _TYPE` and so on)

That should do it.